# calculate each in and out duration for an id

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I've data like below

| Id | date | time | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 | 08:00 | in |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 | 11:30 | out |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 | 11:35 | out |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 | 12:45 | in |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 | 17:30 | out |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 | 01:00 | out |

***expected output :***

| Id | start | end | totaltime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08:00 | 11:35 | 03:35:00 |
| 1 | 12:45 | 17:30 | 04:45:00 |

where **`date`** is of **`DATE`** and `time` is of **`VARCHAR`** type columns. I want to calculate, all in/out duration for an Id. I am not able to think logic how get duration for all in/out duration for this.

Can anyone suggest any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you have date and time column when hours, minutes and seconds are stored in date as well.

Comment: @ToniAntunović, yes make sense, date can be ignored I guess

Comment: @ToniAntunović, any suggestions to solve this ?

Comment: What datatape is your time column?

Comment: Is "date" column of type string or date?

Comment: date is of date type and time is of varchar type

Comment: It badly depends on how in/out rows are disrtibuted over time. What if `(in, in, out, in,out out)` ?

Answer (score 3):

It's a typical [**`gaps-and-islands`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands+oracle) type of question, and one option to resolve would be conditionally using **`SUM() OVER ()`** analytic function such as

```
WITH t1 AS
(
 SELECT t.*,
        TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR("date",'yyyy-mm-dd ')||time,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS dt
   FROM t --> your table
), t2 AS
(   
  SELECT t1.*, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'in' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AS rn_in,
         SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'out' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt) AS rn_out,
         CASE WHEN type = 'in' THEN dt END AS "in",
         CASE WHEN type = 'out' THEN dt END AS "out"  
    FROM t1
) 
SELECT id, MIN("in") AS "start", MAX("out") AS "end", MAX("out")-MIN("in") AS "totaltime"
  FROM t2
 WHERE rn_in >= 1 
 GROUP BY id, rn_in
 ORDER BY "start"
```

*where **`"date"`** is considered to be a **`date`** type column, not an ordinary string as commented.*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cce2f420e87178a757f547145ed2d0c1)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, a `DATE` data type is a binary data type consisting of 7-bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and it **ALWAYS** has those components. Given that, there is no point in having separate date and time columns and you can combine your two columns into one and have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Id, datetime, type) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'in'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '11:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'out' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '11:35' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'out' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '12:45' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'in'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '17:30' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'out' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-01-01' + INTERVAL '01:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'out' FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: Another option to create the sample data is to use `TO_DATE('2022-01-01 12:45', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')`.*

Then, from Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row operations on the data:

```sql
SELECT m.*,
       (end_dt - start_dt) DAY TO SECOND AS duration
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY datetime
  MEASURES
    FIRST(ins.datetime) AS start_dt,
    LAST(outs.datetime) AS end_dt
  PATTERN (ins+ outs+)
  DEFINE
    ins  AS type = 'in',
    outs AS type = 'out'
) m
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | START_DT | END_DT | DURATION |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2022-01-01 08:00:00 | 2022-01-01 11:35:00 | +00 03:35:00.000000 |
> | 1 | 2022-01-01 12:45:00 | 2022-01-01 17:30:00 | +00 04:45:00.000000 |

---

If you do keep separate date and time columns (you should not) then you can combine them into a single column before using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT m.*,
       (end_dt - start_dt) DAY TO SECOND AS duration
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         TO_DATE(TO_CHAR("DATE", 'YYYY-MM-DD') || time, 'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI') AS datetime,
         type
  FROM   table_name
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY datetime
  MEASURES
    FIRST(ins.datetime) AS start_dt,
    LAST(outs.datetime) AS end_dt
  PATTERN (ins+ outs+)
  DEFINE
    ins  AS type = 'in',
    outs AS type = 'out'
) m
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1d9dcca5365362561e7314355f60d936)*

Comment: Thanks for showing that feature, but you should query only the 'in' records to show the expected result

Comment: Thank you, glad I learned about that feature...

Answer (score 0):

By one comment I assumed  that every 'in' record got its matching 'out' record on the same day, so I solved it by getting the next 'in' on a day and finding max 'out' in between:

```
with t1 as 
(select ID, "date" , "time" as "start", LEAD("time",1,'24:00') over(partition by id, "date" order by  "time") as "next"
 from test 
 where "type" = 'in'),
t3 as
(select ID,  "start", (select max("time") from test t2
                        where t1.id = t2.id and t1."date" = t2."date" 
                          and t2."type" = 'out' and t2."time" between t1."start"
                          and t1."next" ) as "end"
from t1)
select ID, "start", "end", (case when "end" is null then null else (TO_DSINTERVAL('0 '||"end"||':00') - TO_DSINTERVAL('0 '||"start"||':00'))  end) as totaltime
from t3
```